# Heroku Python App - CSS Not Loading On IPhone Only

Tags: python, css, heroku, responsive-design, flask

First question posted to Stack Overflow but have spent many hours reading answers here :).

I'm creating a Heroku Python app and am using responsive design media queries in my css.  I deploy my app to Heroku and visit *myherokuapp*.herokuapp.com. Website looks fine on laptop browser...responsive design elements working as well.  Visiting the same url on my iPhone, however, seems to show a page where one of my css files (the media queries) is loading but the other (the main css file) is not.

Does Heroku cache css files?  I read somewhere that you have to host static files elsewhere if you have a Django app, but not sure if that's applicable to me.  I'm also using the Flask function `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">`.  Does that have anything to do with it?

Edit: Does anyone know how to run the equivalent of the Firefox/Google Inspector on mobile?  That would really help me figure out what files are there and what aren't.

Comment: Weinre is an awesome tool for running the webkit inspector on mobile devices: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Bug found.  It was a very, very obscure rendering issue with the text-indent css attribute that only seemed to affect the iPhone 5.

Additionally, if you ever need to debug Google Chrome for iPhone, clearing the cache won't do anything if you don't delete the app from the multitasking menu too (the bar that comes up when you double tap the home button).  That literally took me half an hour to figure out.